# Python external executable output as a two-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, windows

How to get external executable's output as a two-dimensional array?

```
import os
import subprocess 
proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\bin\\test.exe', '-b10.10.2000','-house50.20E,10.40N','-hsyE','-utc00.18','-eswe','-sid27','-fPls','-head','-g'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

output -

```
>>> print (proc)
(b'Sun            \t 173.1483122\t  0.9880656\r\nMoon           \t 313.0306463\t 12.386413
2\r\nMercury        \t 198.1580011\t  0.7897290\r\nVenus          \t 204.8965900\t  1.2175
754\r\nMars           \t 140.5897149\t  0.6242807\r\nJupiter        \t 47.2090321\t -0.035
0736\r\nSaturn         \t 36.4696238\t -0.0472129\r\nUranus         \t 293.1678525\t -0.01
36009\r\nNeptune        \t 279.9571737\t -0.0031065\r\nPluto          \t 226.9850014\t  0.
0259009\r\nmean Node      \t 86.2385757\t -0.0529828\r\ntrue Node      \t 86.8486961\t -0.
1297016\r\nmean Apogee    \t 270.9593053\t  0.1107212\r\nhouse  1       \t 135.1767780\r\n
house  2       \t 165.1767780\r\nhouse  3       \t 195.1767780\r\nhouse  4       \t 225.17
67780\r\nhouse  5       \t 255.1767780\r\nhouse  6       \t 285.1767780\r\nhouse  7
\t 315.1767780\r\nhouse  8       \t 345.1767780\r\nhouse  9       \t 15.1767780\r\nhouse 1
0       \t 45.1767780\r\nhouse 11       \t 75.1767780\r\nhouse 12       \t 105.1767780\r\n
Ascendant      \t 135.1767780\r\nMC             \t 46.8522202\r\nARMC           \t 69.1022
636\r\nVertex         \t 351.3888546\r\nequat. Asc.    \t 133.5633351\r\nco-Asc. W.Koch \t
 131.6974530\r\nco-Asc Munkasey\t 149.4317411\r\nPolar Asc.     \t 311.6974530\r\n', None)

>>>
```

The array should be like this original output -

```
Sun              173.1483122      0.9880656
Moon             313.0306463     12.3864132
Mercury          198.1580011      0.7897290
Venus            204.8965900      1.2175754
Mars             140.5897149      0.6242807
Jupiter          47.2090321      -0.0350736
Saturn           36.4696238      -0.0472129
Uranus           293.1678525     -0.0136009
Neptune          279.9571737     -0.0031065
Pluto            226.9850014      0.0259009
mean Node        86.2385757      -0.0529828
true Node        86.8486961      -0.1297016
mean Apogee      270.9593053      0.1107212
house  1         135.1767780
house  2         165.1767780
house  3         195.1767780
house  4         225.1767780
house  5         255.1767780
house  6         285.1767780
house  7         315.1767780
house  8         345.1767780
house  9         15.1767780
house 10         45.1767780
house 11         75.1767780
house 12         105.1767780
Ascendant        135.1767780
MC               46.8522202
ARMC             69.1022636
Vertex           351.3888546
equat. Asc.      133.5633351
co-Asc. W.Koch   131.6974530
co-Asc Munkasey  149.4317411
Polar Asc.       311.6974530
0
```

Comment: it is normal string - so use string function to create two-dimensional list - you have text.split('\n') to create rows, and text.split('\t') to create columns in every row. OR it looks like CSV file - with tabs instead of commas - so you could use `csv` module to read it . You would need `io.StringIO` to create fake file in memory with your data.

Comment: @furas I modified my question, see the expected array structure.

Comment: my comment still can give you expected result.

Comment: @furasIs there a way to process it for array structure at the first place when retrieved from the execution, instead of processing it as text file later?

Comment: as I said in previous comment: you have string and you can use `split('\n')`, `split('\t')`, `strip()` to reacreate structure - 2-dimensional list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like CSV file (Comma Separated Values) but with tabs instead of commas.

So you could save data in file and use module `csv` to read it.

Or you can use `io.StringIO` to create fake file in memory and use `csv` to read it

```
data = (b'Sun            \t 173.1483122\t  0.9880656\r\nMoon           \t 313.0306463\t 12.386413\
2\r\nMercury        \t 198.1580011\t  0.7897290\r\nVenus          \t 204.8965900\t  1.2175\
754\r\nMars           \t 140.5897149\t  0.6242807\r\nJupiter        \t 47.2090321\t -0.035\
0736\r\nSaturn         \t 36.4696238\t -0.0472129\r\nUranus         \t 293.1678525\t -0.01\
36009\r\nNeptune        \t 279.9571737\t -0.0031065\r\nPluto          \t 226.9850014\t  0.\
0259009\r\nmean Node      \t 86.2385757\t -0.0529828\r\ntrue Node      \t 86.8486961\t -0.\
1297016\r\nmean Apogee    \t 270.9593053\t  0.1107212\r\nhouse  1       \t 135.1767780\r\n\
house  2       \t 165.1767780\r\nhouse  3       \t 195.1767780\r\nhouse  4       \t 225.17\
67780\r\nhouse  5       \t 255.1767780\r\nhouse  6       \t 285.1767780\r\nhouse  7\
\t 315.1767780\r\nhouse  8       \t 345.1767780\r\nhouse  9       \t 15.1767780\r\nhouse 1\
0       \t 45.1767780\r\nhouse 11       \t 75.1767780\r\nhouse 12       \t 105.1767780\r\n\
Ascendant      \t 135.1767780\r\nMC             \t 46.8522202\r\nARMC           \t 69.1022\
636\r\nVertex         \t 351.3888546\r\nequat. Asc.    \t 133.5633351\r\nco-Asc. W.Koch \t\
 131.6974530\r\nco-Asc Munkasey\t 149.4317411\r\nPolar Asc.     \t 311.6974530\r\n', None)

import io
import csv

# output from process
text = data[0].decode()
print(text)

# create fake file in memory with text data
fake_file = io.StringIO(text)

# create CSV reader
reader = csv.reader(fake_file, delimiter='\t')

# read all data from CSV file    
data = list(reader)

# remove spaces
data = [[x.strip() for x in row] for row in data]

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Result - rows

```
['Sun', '173.1483122', '0.9880656']
['Moon', '313.0306463', '12.3864132']
['Mercury', '198.1580011', '0.7897290']
['Venus', '204.8965900', '1.2175754']
['Mars', '140.5897149', '0.6242807']
['Jupiter', '47.2090321', '-0.0350736']
['Saturn', '36.4696238', '-0.0472129']
['Uranus', '293.1678525', '-0.0136009']
['Neptune', '279.9571737', '-0.0031065']
['Pluto', '226.9850014', '0.0259009']
['mean Node', '86.2385757', '-0.0529828']
['true Node', '86.8486961', '-0.1297016']
['mean Apogee', '270.9593053', '0.1107212']
['house  1', '135.1767780']
['house  2', '165.1767780']
['house  3', '195.1767780']
['house  4', '225.1767780']
['house  5', '255.1767780']
['house  6', '285.1767780']
['house  7', '315.1767780']
['house  8', '345.1767780']
['house  9', '15.1767780']
['house 10', '45.1767780']
['house 11', '75.1767780']
['house 12', '105.1767780']
['Ascendant', '135.1767780']
['MC', '46.8522202']
['ARMC', '69.1022636']
['Vertex', '351.3888546']
['equat. Asc.', '133.5633351']
['co-Asc. W.Koch', '131.6974530']
['co-Asc Munkasey', '149.4317411']
['Polar Asc.', '311.6974530']
```

---

**Second method:**

Your data from process is a string so you can also use `split('\n')`, `split('\t')`, `strip()` to create 2-dimensional list.

```
data = (b'Sun            \t 173.1483122\t  0.9880656\r\nMoon           \t 313.0306463\t 12.386413\
2\r\nMercury        \t 198.1580011\t  0.7897290\r\nVenus          \t 204.8965900\t  1.2175\
754\r\nMars           \t 140.5897149\t  0.6242807\r\nJupiter        \t 47.2090321\t -0.035\
0736\r\nSaturn         \t 36.4696238\t -0.0472129\r\nUranus         \t 293.1678525\t -0.01\
36009\r\nNeptune        \t 279.9571737\t -0.0031065\r\nPluto          \t 226.9850014\t  0.\
0259009\r\nmean Node      \t 86.2385757\t -0.0529828\r\ntrue Node      \t 86.8486961\t -0.\
1297016\r\nmean Apogee    \t 270.9593053\t  0.1107212\r\nhouse  1       \t 135.1767780\r\n\
house  2       \t 165.1767780\r\nhouse  3       \t 195.1767780\r\nhouse  4       \t 225.17\
67780\r\nhouse  5       \t 255.1767780\r\nhouse  6       \t 285.1767780\r\nhouse  7\
\t 315.1767780\r\nhouse  8       \t 345.1767780\r\nhouse  9       \t 15.1767780\r\nhouse 1\
0       \t 45.1767780\r\nhouse 11       \t 75.1767780\r\nhouse 12       \t 105.1767780\r\n\
Ascendant      \t 135.1767780\r\nMC             \t 46.8522202\r\nARMC           \t 69.1022\
636\r\nVertex         \t 351.3888546\r\nequat. Asc.    \t 133.5633351\r\nco-Asc. W.Koch \t\
 131.6974530\r\nco-Asc Munkasey\t 149.4317411\r\nPolar Asc.     \t 311.6974530\r\n', None)

text = data[0].decode()
print(text)

data = [[x.strip() for x in row.split('\t')] for row in text.split('\n') if row.strip()]
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Result is the same as in first method.

Comment: I liked the second method.

Comment: second method was my first idea and I mentioned it in comment as first. Method with CSV can be useful with more complex array - when there is tab in text which doesn't seperate columns - ie. `"Hello \t World"`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = list(list(s.strip() for s in row.split('\\t')) for row in str(proc[0]).split('\\r\\n'))
```

Comment: couldn't get the output as separate lines